# Create a chi-square table from 4 columns and pair 2 of the values together to make one dependent and other indenpendent

Tags: r, pivot, chi-squared, temp

I have a list of columns below.

```
col 1|col 2|col 3|col 4|col 5|Yes Col_B|No Col_B|Yes Col_W|No Col_W
 1      1      3     3     5          7        9        3         2
```

What i would like to do is take the last four columns and take Yes Col_B, No Col_B, Yes Col_W, and No Col_W and then imagine them as two columns

```
Yes or No| B or W
       7       B
       9       B
       3       W
       2       W
```

Now that i have two temporary columns I could run a chisquare to indicate if Yes or No is dependent on B or W

```
 test <- chisq.test(table(data$YesorNo, data$BorW))
```

Comment: Why do you want the column `Yes or No` to have the observation value? Shouldn't it be a column indicating if the variable was `Yes` or `No`, and then have a third column with the values?

Comment: You are correct. I should add that in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another version to Ricardo, where most of the name splitting and separation is accomplished within the `pivot_longer` function:

```
df<-data.frame(`Yes Col_B`=7, `No Col_B`=9, `Yes Col_W`=3, `No Col_W`=2) 

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

answer <- pivot_longer(df, contains("Col_"), names_sep = "_", names_to=c("Yes_No", ".value")) %>% 
               mutate(Yes_No=str_replace(Yes_No, "\\.Col", ""))

answer
## A tibble: 2 x 3
#  Yes_No     B     W
#  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
#1 Yes        7     3
#2 No         9     8

chisq.test(answer[ , c("B", "W")])
#since counts are less than 5 suggest the Fisher's Exact Test
fisher.test(answer[ , c("B", "W")])
```

The chi^2 test generally needs at least 5 members per category for analysis, thus I have included the Fisher's Exact test as alternative.

Answer (score 2):

First we use `pivot_longer` from `tidyr`, and set it to create one group (line) for every column:

```
newdf = tidyr::pivot_longer(df[,6:9], cols=everything())
```

Which gives:

```
  name      value
1 Yes Col_B     7
2 No Col_B      9
3 Yes Col_W     3
4 No Col_W      2
```

Now we need to separate the `name` column into two, one for the yes or no, one for the B or W. We do that with finding a pattern in those names (regular expressions):

The pattern is (yes or no)( Col_)(B or W), we write that as `"(Yes|No) Col_(B|W)"`. Then we run a loop to create one column for the first group - where the groups are set by the brackets - (given by `"\\1"`), and another for the second (`"\\2"`), and use `paste0("\\",i)` to do this.

```
newdf = cbind(NA, NA, newdf) #Creating 2 empty columns

for(i in c(1,2)){
  newdf[,i] = gsub("(Yes|No) Col_(B|W)",
                   paste0("\\",i),
                   newdf$name)}

newdf$name = NULL #Getting rid of the name column
colnames(newdf) = c("Yes or No", "B or W", "Value")
```

Output:

```
  Yes or No B or W Value
1       Yes      B     7
2        No      B     9
3       Yes      W     3
4        No      W     2
```