# How can i properly arrange this in a two by two using R and pivot longer function?

Tags: r, pivot

the dataset is

```
structure(list(`total first - yes RS` = 138L, `total first - no RS` = 29L, 
`total second- yes rs` = 6L, `total second- no rs` = 0L), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

which looks like

```
total first -yes RS|total first -no RS|total second -yes rs|total second -no rs
               76                  20                 12                    0
```

What i would like to do is create a two by two where I have

```
          total first| total second
   Yes rs     76    12
    No rs     20     0
```

Comment: similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66709712/create-a-chi-square-table-from-4-columns-and-pair-2-of-the-values-together-to-ma/66710695#66710695

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the input dataset, the delimiter seems to be space followed by a hyphen and some space in the column names.  We can specify the `names_sep` in `pivot_longer` as `"\\s*-\\s*"` i.e. zero or more spaces followed by a hyphen and zero or more spaces.  As the column names have lower and upper cases mixed, it is better to convert to a single case before doing the reshaping

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(janitor)
df1 %>%
    rename_all(~ toupper(.)) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = c(".value", "grp"), 
         names_sep = "\\s*-\\s*") %>% 
    column_to_rownames('grp')
```

Comment: "\\s*-\\s*", the * means end?

Comment: @user35131 the `\\s` means space `*` implies zero or more i..e zero or more space

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option but with base R function `reshape`

```
subset(reshape(
  cbind(q = "",
        setNames(df, tolower(
          gsub("\\s?-\\s?", ".", names(df))
        ))),
  direction = "long",
  idvar = "q",
  varying = -1
),
select = -c(q, time))
```

which gives

```
        total first total second
.yes rs         138            6
.no rs           29            0
```